# Moving a GameObject inside canvas to touchpoint

Tags: android, canvas, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am new to Unity 3D and was following Udemy tutorials for learning the platform.
I developed a game GoHippoGo in the course, where an image of a Hippo moves around the screen to the point of touch.

Although when I tried to use canvas and panels etc... to make the game suitable for all screen sizes, the hippo stopped moving !! When touched it only fell down out of the screen ( that too very slowly ), instead of moving to the touch point.

I tried searching all over the internet, even the unity forums, but couldn't find a solution.
My mistake might be very obvious, but since I am a novice, please cooperate :P

Thank You

Here is a screenshot of my canvas :
[image]

Here is my MoveHippo script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveHippo : MonoBehaviour {

    private float lastTouchTime, currentTouchTime;

    public float velocityVal;
    public float torqueVal;
    public float thresholdTime;


    void Awake() {
        velocityVal = 8.0f;
        torqueVal = 200.0f;
        thresholdTime = 0.3f;
    }

    void Update () {

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        moveHippoAndroid ();
    #endif

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        moveHippo();
    #endif  
    }

    void moveHippo() { //For testing only in your COMPUTER
        Vector3 currentPos, touchedPos, distanceVec;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            startRotatingHippoAndStopIt();
        }

        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            currentPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
            touchedPos = Input.mousePosition;
            distanceVec = (touchedPos - currentPos).normalized;
            stopRotatingHippoAndMoveIt(distanceVec, velocityVal);
        }
    }

    void moveHippoAndroid() { 
        Vector3 currentPos, touchedPos, distanceVec;        
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touches.Length; i++) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
            currentPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
            touchedPos = touch.position;
            distanceVec = (touchedPos - currentPos).normalized;
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                startRotatingHippoAndStopIt();
            } else if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                currentTouchTime = Time.time;
                if (currentTouchTime - lastTouchTime > thresholdTime) { //No Double Touch detected ...
                    lastTouchTime = Time.time;
                    stopRotatingHippoAndMoveIt(distanceVec, velocityVal);
                } else if (currentTouchTime - lastTouchTime < thresholdTime){ //Double Touch detected!
                    lastTouchTime = Time.time;
                    stopRotatingHippoAndMoveIt(distanceVec, velocityVal*2.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void startRotatingHippoAndStopIt() {
        // We rorate the hippo...
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().fixedAngle = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddTorque(torqueVal);

        // ... and stop it
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=Vector2.zero;
    }

    void stopRotatingHippoAndMoveIt(Vector3 distanceVec, float velocity) {
        // We stop rotating the hippo...
        Quaternion hippoQuatern = new Quaternion();
        hippoQuatern.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().fixedAngle = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.rotation = hippoQuatern;

        // ... and move it.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = distanceVec*velocity;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the MoveHippo script attached to? The camera or the Hippo?

Comment: The MoveHippo script is attached to the Hippo

Answer (score 1):

Try using `(RectTransform)transform.position` or `GetComponent<RectTransform>().position` (or simply `transform.position` but I like to remember I'm dealing with a **RectTransform** and not a standard **Transform**) instead of `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position)` : since your **Canvas** is set to *Screen Space - Overlay*, the global position of the **RectTransform** component will return the X,Y,Z values in pixel coordinates.

*If your screen is 800x600 and your object is centered, `GetComponent<RectTransform>().position` will return (400.0f, 300.0f, 0.0f).*

Comment: I did what you said, now the hippo is moving towards the touch point, but very very very slowly. Velocity is set to 8.0f, but it never seems to reach the destination.

Comment: I get where the problem is, the entire scene view is of just 1 unit. When I Logged the distanceVec , it showed values of x, y coordinates b/w 0-1, and z was 0. I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Comment: @ayuschjain The scene view isn't really 1 unit : **distanceVec** values are between -1 and 1 because the vector is normalized (also _distanceVec.z= 0_ because you're in 2D when using a Canvas : _z_ is "related" to depth). If you want to increase the speed of the hippo simply increase **velocityVal** (something like 100.0f). If you want to achieve a kind of slow braking you have to set a value to the _Rigidbody2D.Linear Drag_ property (something like 0.5f).

Comment: When I do just as the Udemy tutorial ie. without using canvas, the distanceVec values are not in b/w -1 to 1, it's greater than that. Vector was normalised there as well. I even tried to increase the velocityVal , but no use.....:(

Comment: @ayuschjain Uhm... I feel like something is wrong : if you normalize a vector, its length (magnitude) will become 1 so none of its components can be lower than -1 and bigger than 1 (look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html) for `Vector3.normalized`) informations. Also I tried your script with the changes I suggested on a **Rigidbody2D** with the values I gave in my previous comment and it worked well.

Comment: changing velocityVal to 100.0f didn't work for me :((